# How do I make the collapsible button appear only in mobile view?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

What I want to achieve, is to make the collapsible button appear only in mobile view.

This is my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
        <!--Nav bar-->
        <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!--content inside navbar-->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <h1>Food, LLC</h1>

                    
                </div>

                <!--collapsible button for mobile users-->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" 
                data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>
    <script src="jquery/code.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using the *Twitter Bootstrap CSS Framework 4.5.3* in this case.

My actual output:

[image: this]

As you can see, a small line is visible in the right side, irrespective of the display size (mobile, tablet or desktop).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of bootstrap are you using ?

Try adding these classes to your collapsible button `.d-block .d-sm-none`.
[Check the bootstrap doc here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/) which explains the display properties.

Or a better solution, use the `.navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}` within your navbar.

If you were using bootstrap 4, you had several problems in using the [nav component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/)

### Edit with code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
        <!--Nav bar-->
        <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Food, LLC</a>
                    </li>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```